# how to add items to the UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to iPhone development. 
my application is based on UInavigationBar .
I want to add a navigation bar item in one of my xib, but in the .xib i just simulate the navigation bar so i can't drag and drop the item. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add the nav bar buttons programmatically. You see, your xib has a view that is shown within the content view of the UINavigationController. It is the UINavigationBar to which your app has access and which controls the nav bar items. As you point out, your xib has just a placeholder for the nav bar, which is really a convenience for you so your view is sized correctly as you lay it out.

In your UIViewController for the xib, you an add view-appropriate nav bar items with code something like

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:@"View" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                           target:self
                                           action:@selector(viewControls:)] autorelease];
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: thank you , the item is added but how can i make to call a method when i click on it ?

Comment: The `target` and `action` are the object and method of the object, respectively, to be called when the button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to add items into a UINavigationBar, you need to first add a UINavigationBar to your view and then add items to it.

You cannot drag and drop items on a simulated navigation bar. A simulated Navigation Bar is just there to make sure you have a correct estimate of the view size available to you if you are adding a Navigation Bar by some other means or from code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a UINavigationController for a navigation based hierarchy. That will take care of a lot of the lower details of how to make navigation work as you would like it to. I would also recommend setting that all up programmatically. Here is how you would do that.

```
// Initial setup of navigation
YourViewController *yvc = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yvc];
[[self view] addSubview:[nav view]];
```

Then when you want to go to a new view controller (the animated sliding that you normally see), you do this

```
// From inside 'YourViewController', 
// this is normally when the user touches a table view cell
NewViewController *nvc = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nvc];
```

If you want to change the title or the buttons, you do this

```
// This is normally in viewDidLoad or something similar
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Hello World!"];
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem:/* A UIBarButtonItem */];
```